# Why does this code run twice?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get the active title bar and test it if it equals certain value, I open a new browser window. I used the code below inside a timer tick event

The problem is that on each timer tick, the Process.Start will run twice, which means I see two windows of firefox opening the page www.googlepromo.com.

```
public static void timerTick()
    {

 foreach (string s in ttlkeywords) {
                    if ((GetActiveWindowTitle().Contains(s)) && s.Length>2)
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.googlepromo.com");
                        Thread.Sleep(60000);

                    }
                }

}
```

The function below is the one I use to get the active title bar. I don't think the problem is in the function below but I write it anyway:

```
   // Detect active windows Title Bar
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);

    private static string GetActiveWindowTitle()
    {
        const int nChars = 256;
        IntPtr handle = IntPtr.Zero;
        StringBuilder Buff = new StringBuilder(nChars);
        handle = GetForegroundWindow();

        if (GetWindowText(handle, Buff, nChars) > 0)
        {
            return Buff.ToString();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The timer :

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
                    timer.Interval = 5000;
                    timer.OnTimerTick += timerTick;
                    Thread timerThread = timer.Start();

                    timer.Run();
```

Can someone please explain why the browser windows run twice instead of just a single time ?

Comment: What is the content of `ttlkeywords`?

Comment: public static string[] ttlkeywords = File.ReadAllLines("keywords.txt");

Comment: Well, but the actual values loaded from the file? I think it is important because if Contains finds partial matches it could trigger your process start more than one time

Comment: What is the value of `GetWindowTitle()` and what are the values of `ttlkeywords`?

Comment: The GetWindowTitle() return a string of the active window title, for example "c# - Why does this code run twice? - Stack Overflow" and the ttlkeywords is string array that read lines from a text file (the text file contain keywords, 1 keyword each line)

Comment: Well, suppose that your keyword file contains the words "Stack Overflow" and "C#". How many time Process.Start will be called if this question is open?

Comment: I tried it. It opens 2 times. But if there was only one keyword in the text file, it will open 2 times also

Comment: I also tried to use break; just after the process.start(..) but it still open twice.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `foreach`, and get the values of `ttlkeywords`, and write them here. What are the values of `ttlkeywords`? What is the length of that array? Don't tell me what you expect the values to be, but rather what you see they are.

Comment: Also, different approach, disable the timer, and call `Process.Start` outside of timer, where you know it will be called only once, and see what happens then.

Comment: @Dialecticus I cant put a breakpoint as I'm compiling the file at runtime with codedom. I have edited my post, please see the way I'm implementing the timer. Do you think it contain any mistake ?

Comment: I won't try to guess. There must be a way to debug the code, and to see values of the variables in the code. That's essential, even in that codedom thingy, whatever it is. If all else fails use `MessageBox` to show it.

Comment: Use `Debugger.Break` to launch the debugger programmatically.

Comment: @shikata this is not a solution. As soon as timing happens to be a little off you will experience the bug again.