# Easiest way to prevent a process from being started if it was already open?

Tags: c#

I have a form with a timer on it. On timer Tick Event I have the following code:

```
  private void timer1_Tick(...) {
  Process.Start("http://www.google.com");
  }
```

I want whenever the tick event is fired, **the webpage will open only if it wasn't already open.**

Comment: Can you show your current code so we know what you tried so far?

Comment: In fact, I need an answer to another question that confused me, so I simplified the question here, if I can solve this then I will solve the other question, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20773517/why-does-this-code-run-twice?noredirect=1#comment31141813_20773517

Comment: It'll be a bit tricky. It's *not a process you're starting*, but a webpage you're browsing. This can either open a new tab in an existing process or spawn a new one (which we don't know because we don't know the browser)

Comment: There's no easy way to do this, because you don't know what the user's default browser is. The only thing I could think of is you'd have to scan the open window titles using Win API calls (P/Invokes) to see if there was a title with "Google" in it, but that's certainly not easy nor clean.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer to your question but a suggestion to try a different approach.

You can try putting the [`WebBrowser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control on a form (Winform) instead of launching a new browser window. This way you'd have complete control over when and what link to open instead of trying to figure out from the system (and from the various browsers) if a given web page is already open. The `WebBrowser` control gives you a fair amount of control over the properties / events of the underlying browser window so you'd likely have an easier time doing what you're trying to do.

You'd have to add your own address bar / toolbar (if you need any of these) but that's still a lot less work doing it that way. There are certain things that you cannot do using `WebBrowser` but they'd be next to impossible to do using your current approach anyway.

To give an actual (incomplete) answer to your question: it's possible to achieve what you're trying to do but it's fairly tricky and not completely reliable. Personally I wouldn't waste time with it.

**Edit**: as SpikeX recommended in a comment, you can also use [Awesomium](http://www.awesomium.com/) as an embedded browser. I didn't know about it before.

Comment: This is a good suggestion, using `Process.Start` has (almost) no control over what happens after it's started, but embedding a web browser allows for much more control. I'd also like to recommend [**Awesomium**](http://www.awesomium.com/) as an embedded alternative to the `WebBrowser` control, because Awesomium runs on the Chrome engine vs. an outdated IE engine.

Comment: @SpikeX Yes, that's a good suggestion, I didn't know about it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want some process to be fired only one time don't use a timer for this. Call the process inside your Mainwindow constructor, the Loaded event of the window, or inside a click event of a button. Another way is to use a counter, and in the tick method to increment it. All you have to do is to stop the timer if this counter equals 1, by writing Timer.Stop();

Comment: This is not what the asker is looking for, please re-read the question.

Comment: It is a valid answer.  The premise of the question is deeply flawed.